# how to remove X10 from "X4/X2/X10/" in TCL?

Tags: tcl

the input is "X4/X2/X10/". I want to remove X10 from this. The required output is "X4/X2/". what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [string](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) subcommands:

```
set input "X4/X2/X10/"

# find the index of the last slash before the end of string slash
set idx [string last / $input end-1]  ;# => 5

set new [string range $input 0 $idx]  ;# => X4/X2/
```

Or, together

```
set new [string range $input 0 [string last / $input end-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways. Here's one that turns the input into a list of pieces, uses `lsearch` to do the filtering of that list, and then reassembles the result aftwards:

```
set input "X4/X2/X10/"

set pieces [split $input "/"]
set removed [lsearch -inline -all -not -exact $pieces "X10"]
set output [join $removed "/"]

puts $output
```

Comment: thanks for answering. sorry my question was unclear. what I intended was to remove the last element not specifically for X10. sorry TCL newbie here

Answer (score 0):

> what I intended was to remove the last element not specifically for X10

Something like

```
set input "X4/X2/X10/"
set output [join [lreplace [split $input /] end-1 end-1] /]
puts $output
```

works for that.

Answer (score 0):

I like glenn's answer for the spirit of working a string when one needs a string as output. Similar, consider using [`regexp`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm):

```
% set input "X4/X2/X10/"
% regexp {(.*/)[^/]+/$} $input _ output 
% set output
X4/X2/
```